# GoogleMaps markers don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put three Google Maps markers on a website, but they don't work. I can't figure it out why. I've checked all over again, several times, but I'm a newbie and I can't find the problem.

Here's my JS code

```
<!-- Google Maps JS -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--[if IE 8]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function initialize() {

        //Locations Coordinates
        var myLatlngBusto = new google.maps.LatLng(45.6084,8.850165);
        var myLatlngMagnago = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5808394,8.850165);
        var myLatlngBienate = new google.maps.LatLng(51.520614,-0.121825);

        //Options List
        var mapOptionsBusto = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlngOH,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: 0
        }

        var mapOptionsMagnago = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlngCA,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: 0
        }

        var mapOptionsBienate = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlngUK,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: 0
        }

        //Maps Variables
        var mapBusto = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-Busto'), mapOptionsBusto);
        var mapMagnago = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-Magnago'), mapOptionsMagnago);
        var mapBienate = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-Bienate'), mapOptionsBienate);

        //Markers List
        var markerBusto = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlngBusto,
            map: mapBusto,
            title: 'Busto Arsizio, via Dante Alighieri, 5'
        });

        var markerMagnago = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlngMagnago,
            map: mapMagnago,
            title: 'Magnago, via Goffredo Mameli, 9'
        });      

        var markerBienate = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlngBienate,
            map: mapBienate,
            title: 'Bienate (fraz. Magnago), Piazzale del Tricolore'
        });

    }  
</script>
```

And my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
                <p class="dark-section"><i><strong>Busto Arsizio</strong></i>, via Dante Alighieri 5<br/>Palestra scuola media G.A.Bossi</p><br/>
                <p class="dark-section"><span>ADULTI:</span><br/>lunedì e giovedì<br/>Inizio ore 20.30, fine ore 22.00</p><br/>
                <p class="dark-section"><span>BAMBINI:</span><br/>mercoledì e venerdì<br/>Inizio ore 17.00, fine ore 18.30</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <a href="https://www.google.it/maps/place/Via+Dante+Alighieri,+5,+21052+Busto+Arsizio+VA/@45.6084,8.850165,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47868b8f5fcdbda1:0xc536e6f9f778dea" target="_blank"><div id="map-Busto"></div></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="hr5" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <br/>
                <p class="dark-section"><i><strong>Magnago</strong></i>, via Goffredo Mameli 9<br/>Palestra scuola elementare Ada Negri</p><br/>
                <p class="dark-section"><span>ADULTI:</span><br/>martedì e venerdì<br/>inizio ore 21.00, fine ore 23.00</p><br/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <a href="https://www.google.it/maps/place/Via+Goffredo+Mameli,+9,+20020+Magnago+MI/@45.5808394,8.8014125,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47868adf70308f8d:0x9373e8e46d562c9f" target="_blank"><div id="map-Magnago"></div></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="hr5" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <br/>
                <p class="dark-section"><i><strong>Bienate (fraz. Magnago)</strong></i>, Piazzale del Tricolore<br/>Palestra scuola elementare Giacomo Leopardi</p><br/>
                <p class="dark-section"><span>BAMBINI:</span><br/>lunedì e giovedì<br/>Inizio ore 18.30, fine ore 20.00</p><br/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <a href="https://www.google.it/maps/place/Piazza+Tricolore,+20020+Magnago+MI/@45.5778806,8.8173467,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47868b3c7573abc9:0xd99dc1eade985c9c" target="_blank"><div id="map-Bienate"></div></a>
            </div>
```

Here you can check the result on the website page: http://westexperiments.altervista.org/index.html

So how do I fix these Google Maps markers?

Comment: Hi you have create the function `initialize()` but you didn't call to the `initialize();` to start the thing. Please make sure to call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

- The function `initialize` has not been called so the maps wont ever get generated. This can be called on window load by using `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`
- You are using the variables `myLatlngOH`, `myLatlngCA` and `myLatlngUK` to center the maps - they don't exist and will stop the maps from being generated. I assume these should be `myLatlngBusto`, `myLatlngMagnago` and `myLatlngBienate` instead

```js
function initialize() {
    //Locations Coordinates
    var myLatlngBusto = new google.maps.LatLng(45.6084, 8.850165);
    var myLatlngMagnago = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5808394, 8.850165);
    var myLatlngBienate = new google.maps.LatLng(51.520614, -0.121825);

    //Options List
    var mapOptionsBusto = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlngBusto,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: 0
    }

    var mapOptionsMagnago = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlngMagnago,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: 0
    }

    var mapOptionsBienate = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlngBienate,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: 0
    }

    //Maps Variables
    var mapBusto = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-Busto'), mapOptionsBusto);
    var mapMagnago = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-Magnago'), mapOptionsMagnago);
    var mapBienate = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-Bienate'), mapOptionsBienate);

    //Markers List
    var markerBusto = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlngBusto,
        map: mapBusto,
        title: 'Busto Arsizio, via Dante Alighieri, 5'
    });

    var markerMagnago = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlngMagnago,
        map: mapMagnago,
        title: 'Magnago, via Goffredo Mameli, 9'
    });

    var markerBienate = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlngBienate,
        map: mapBienate,
        title: 'Bienate (fraz. Magnago), Piazzale del Tricolore'
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js"></script>
<div id="map-Busto"></div>
<div id="map-Magnago"></div>
<div id="map-Bienate"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't trigger initialize().

Add this, at the bottom of your script (line 121 of your online example):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```